# RVIZ drops 100% of messages

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rviz has been dropping 100% of broadcasted messages despite finding the published nodes and subscribing to them.
It has something to do with my ROS_IP and ROS_MASTER_URI because it works fine when ROS_MASTER_URI is not set.

Here is an example situation to reproduce my error:

In three terminals do:

export ROS_IP=

export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://${ROS_IP}:11311      // this works, it looks like: http://10.0.26.191:11311

then in one terminal run roscore, in another launch a camera node, and in the last run rviz.

Despite the fact that I can use image_view to see the images from the camera node, rviz can't receive any of the messages.

I am trying to broadcast messages across a network and visualize them with rviz, which is why I have this setup.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233541/rviz-drops-100%-of-messages/) by [halfpotato](https://answers.ros.org/users/26291/halfpotato/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-05-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2016-05-03**:
This sounds like a networking issue. I'd recommend just using `rostopic echo` (rather than `rviz`) to simplify things. I'd also recommend trying to use `netcat` to test your network settings: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup#Further_check:_netcat

**Comment by [halfpotato](https://answers.ros.org/users/26291/halfpotato/) on 2016-05-03**:
The thing is, image_view can receive the images while rviz cannot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Rviz dropping messages is frequently related with problems on the timestamps of the messages. Please check how these timestaps are being published in both the image topic and in the camera_info topics.

---

Originally posted by [IvanV](https://answers.ros.org/users/9801/ivanv/) with karma: 329 on 2016-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1